# Oracle Apex 5.1 Dynamic parameter

Tags: oracle-apex

I have some parameter in my apex report.
when i set the parameter value in my code, like this:

```
AND ifl.id = :P53_ifl
```

when run this query with below static id (set 18 in my query):

```
AND ifl.id = 18
```

my report apply fast(about 4 minute)

but when parameter is dynamic and send from apex it was answer very late (about 1 hour)

I don't know what is my problem?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that doesn't make a difference & it shouldn't make a difference. I presume `:P53_ifl`'s value is also 18? Did you run that query in some other tool (such as SQL Developer)? Did you check explain plan?

Comment: @Littlefoot    I do this in SQL Developer but in there with  **ifl.id = 18** answer me **very late** (about 20 min) but when use **NVL(18,ifl.id) = ifl.id** answer **very fast** (about 12's)

Comment: You should run both options several times to avoid caching issues. By the way, `nvl(18, ifl.id)` doesn't make any sense. 18 is never null.

Comment: I tried many times but the answer was same. by the way i want use NVL in my Apex app with dynamic parameter and there was another problem. Apex don't let me to use this : q:= q || ' and nvl(' || :P53_INS_FIELD || ' , ifl.id) = ifl.id';   q is my string query. this wrong in Apex. error is (Failed to parse SQL query)